# How to use a Xero api endpoint in asp.net c# webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms, xero-api

In the whole internet I couldn't find complete sample code to use a Xero api endpoint (contacts / Employees / Payments) in asp.net c# webforms and get JSON response and importantly consuming it (whole CRUD functions).

FYI: I am aware of below tutorial; but it is a console application sample.

http://www.webmyriad.net/tips/xero-api/xero-api-compiling-the-c-code-sample-from-source-for-private-applications

From the Xero documentation, I can only get what details are available to fetch.
Example: http://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/contacts/

Somebody please advice/direct me. Thanks.

Comment: It lloks like the API returns XML, not JSON. And are you not capable of taking the relevant bits of code from the tutorial and adapting them to your own app?

Comment: Yes. I am still learning.